What's the underlying reason for salesforce metadata api for not being able to give more deployment errors in one go?
I understand that there are dependency related hidden errors, which can only pop up when a dependent issue is resolved but:
I see it many times (and it's very annoying) that there are no dependency issues during validation (for example against a profile) but still gives me errors one by one. It behaves that it would be stopping validation at the first error (at least for certain type of errors) it encounters and not giving back all the already visible errors.
If there's any idea already posted, that can also be useful, but very interested why they don't improve this.

One way to avoid these issues is to use a commercial devops tool that does pre-deployment problem analysis for missing dependencies, etc.  See, for example, Gearset, Copado, etc.

I think that the main reason could be the Multi-Tenant nature of SF;
Since validating and analyzing every potential error across large deployments will impact server performance. Limiting errors allows Salesforce to maintain fairness and responsiveness across tenants without one deployment taking all the processing power.
